# Finiteness of second moments and correlation of independent random variables

Tags: probability-theory

I am reading the book "A course in Probability by Chung" and I came across the following statement:

> If random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then they are uncorrelated, provided that their second moments are finite.

But, I do not understand why the second moments of $X$ and $Y$ need to be finite in order for $X$ and $Y$ to be uncorrelated.

Don't we have that if $X$ and $Y$ are in $L^1$ and independent, then $XY$ is also in $L^1$ and $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$?

So, even if the second moments of $X$ and $Y$ are not finite, aren't they uncorrelated?

Comment: The assumption of finite second moments is part of Chung's definition of "uncorrelated".  His rationale for this appears at the foot of the page on which the definition is made.

Comment: @JohnDawkins What I am cited above actually comes from his explanation of why he wants finite second moments for general $X$ and $Y$. But, it wans't clear to me why the finite second moments are still needed for independent random variables.

Comment: Second moments are not needed for the truth of  $E[XY]=E[X]E[Y]$ when $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing notions of covariance and correlation. The correlation is a ratio of covariance to the square root of the product of second moments, so the latter have to exist (formally).